# Getting Windows Media Center to recognize chapter marks in .mp4 files

Tags: windows-media-center, mp4, handbrake

I started to convert my DVD collection to .mp4 and despite the fact that Handbrake is adding chapter marks in the .mp4 files, WMC doesn't recognize them and skips forward in the same manner as recorded TV (i.e., skips 30 seconds).

When I play the same video via VLC, it recognizes the chapter marks and skips accordingly.

Is there a way to get WMC to recognize chapter marks in mp4 files?